# How to resolve "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier" in PHP?

Tags: php, html, sql

I keep getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp1\htdocs\Php-Work\index.php on line 69

```
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_products"]) > 0)
{ /*some code*/
```

Comment: i can't seem to find anything wrong with it

Comment: I doubt that this is the line, which throws an error.

Comment: here is my full code:

Comment: Don't post code in the comments. Edit your question

Comment: understood, i'm trying to past my full code into the question box but in

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask